# CodeIgniter 2.1.4 - Routing don't work in server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I know there are many issues like this but I applied everything and I don't find the correct way to do it.

The .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /NewWebsite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /NewWebsite/error.php
</IfModule>
```

In config/config.php :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://mydomain.com/NewWebsite/';  
$config['index_page'] = ''; 
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; // I change it with REQUEST_URI and PATH_INFO but it don't work
```

In server, mod_rewrite is enabled.

In localhost, everything is ok but when i uploaded it to the server, only index works (the first page that you see) but when I want to "move" around the web, i have 404 error, page not found.

I am going to show one controller and how I call it to change to another views.

```
class Products_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->view('products.php');
    }
}
```

And from index, I call it:

```
echo base_url('Products_controller/index');
```

OR

```
echo base_url('Products'); // I have in config/routes.php ---> $route['Products'] = "Products_controller/index";
```

Anyone can help me? What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your hosting provider? .htaccess vary based on hosting provider.

Comment: My hosting provider is hostinet. I ask him for "mod_rewrite" and they said that it was activated, so I can use it.

Comment: Try with my answer and let me know what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally, I got a solution about this topic.It was not about a .htaccess problem, was a really dump and simple mistake.

> In CodeIgniter, the name of the controllers and the name of the file
>   have to have exactly the same name. I have been defining my
>   controllers with the first letter capitalized and not in the file
>   name. And now it is everything ok !

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Though .htaccess depends on hosting server sometimes but you can try with this and let us know. Replace your .htaccess code with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

Thats it.

Comment: I did it and now... when I try to change to the view calling the controller I have described above.. I am redirected to "mydomain.com". I mean, I am trying to get a subdirectory with Codeigniter installed in "mydomain.com/NewWebsite"

Comment: I can try to install it in "mydomain.com" instead of "mydomain.com/NewWebsite" but... it is not the same thing ? It must be a root directory ?

Comment: Please describe your scenario briefly so I can answer you perfectly.

Comment: I want to work CodeIgniter on "mydomain.com/NewWebsite". So in this directory, I put folders (application, system, assets-css,js,images,libraries-, .htaccess ). In localhost works perfectly, in server only I can see the main index. When I try to go "out" from this page, I get error 404. Ask me for any information extra you need to know... I don't understand why it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /NewWebsite/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

The above should work - make sure your `.htaccess` is inside the sub-directory you want to run from.

Also make sure that you don't have a conflicting `.htaccess` rule in the base directory.

Comment: Don't work. When I try to leave index.php, get 404. I don't understand, it must works.

Comment: I tried a new project. Without .htacess so you can see index.php in the URL. Only two controllers, two pages and one goal... to get from one to another. And it fails too. What can it be? it is the server? or what? This gonna make me crazy. I see that URL is in this way: www.domain.com/NewWebsite/ControllerName/FunctionName but always 404 error, page not found.